# Dash callback duplicate issue - Python

Tags: python, function, callback, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have a dashboard built with dash-plotly of this structure:

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(children=[
                     html.Div(children=[dcc.Dropdown(options=[
                                              {'label': 'Viability', 'value':'fig_viability'},
                                              {'label': 'Mean Diameter', 'value': 'fig_diameter'},
                                              {'label': 'Concentration', 'value': 'fig_concentration'}],
                                              id='graph-selector')]]),

                     html.Div(children=[
                                  dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
                                  dcc.Interval(
                                      id='interval-component',
                                      interval=15 * 1000,  # in milliseconds
                                      n_intervals=0)])])])
```

I am trying to make an app displaying 3 different graphs based on the dropdown choice. The thing is that the excel files which serve as a source of data will be changed every couple of minutes. I tried to use "Interval" component to make this live graph update but I think I messed up somewhere in callbacks, as it throws me an error:

"In the callback for output(s):
graph.figure
Output 0 (graph.figure) is already in use.
Any given output can only have one callback that sets it."

My callbacks and excel file manipulations are below:

```
@app.callback(Output('graph', 'children'),
                  [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
    def update_figures(n):
        
    df = pd.read_excel(...)

    fig_viability = px.scatter(df,
                            x="Sample Name",
                            y="Result",
                            color="Sample Name",
                            template='plotly_dark').update_layout(
     {'title': 'Viability Plot (%)',
      'modebar_add': ['v1hovermode', 'toggleSpikelines'],
      'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)'})

      fig_diameter = px.scatter(df,
                          x="Sample Name",
                          y="Mean Diameter (microns)",
                          color="Sample Name",
                         template='plotly_dark').update_layout(
     {'modebar_add': ['v1hovermode', 'toggleSpikelines'],
      'title': 'Mean diameter Plot (microns)',
      'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)'})

      fig_concentration = px.scatter(df,
                               x="Sample Name",
                               y="Concentration",
                               color="Sample Name",
                              template='plotly_dark').update_layout(
      {'title': 'Concentration Plot',
       'modebar_add': ['v1hovermode', 'toggleSpikelines'],
       'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
       'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)'})

    @app.callback(
        Output('graph', 'figure'),
        [Input(component_id='graph-selector', component_property='value')]
    )
    def select_graph(value):
        if value == 'fig_viability':
            return fig_viability
        elif value == 'fig_diameter':
            return fig_diameter
        else:
            return fig_concentration
```

Sorry if that's too wordy, I am newbie to Python and Dash, so tried to give as much detail as possible. Prior to plotting the excel file, three discrete files have to be combined to get this one common file with all the data. The issue is that these files will be changed, as I mentioned earlier, hence the need for live updating.

I hope someone will know how to do it better.. :(

P.S. The data frame looks like this:

```
   Sample Name  Result  Concentration  Mean Diameter
0            A     244            122              8
1            A     150              8              3
2            A     133             78             10
3            B     567             34             40
4            B     122            622              4
5            B     100            180             20
6            C      55             20             12
7            C      10             11             50
8            C      76            230             37
9            D     230             67              2
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version (2.3.0) of Dash, an element can only be targeted as an `Output` by a single callback. You *can* work around the limitation by bundling callbacks with subsequent branching based on the [callback context](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks), but it quickly becomes cumbersome.

An alternative is to use `dash-extensions` (can be installed via pip). After installing, simply replace your dash imports with their counter parts from the `enrich` module,

```
from dash_extensions.enrich import Dash, Input, State, Output, html, dcc
```

and it should work without any code changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this advice! I tried it but it gives me this error:

Invalid prop for this component
10:22:07
Property "children" was used with component ID:
  "graph"
in one of the Output items of a callback.
This ID is assigned to a dash_core_components.Graph component
in the layout, which does not support this property.
This ID was used in the callback(s) for Output(s):
  graph.children

It looks the same as the one which I was getting previously.. Can I just change 'children' to something else?

Comment: That's a different error. As the error says, you are targeting a prop that doesn't exits (the 'Graph' component doesn't have a 'children' property). Looking at your code snippet, I guess that your intention is to target the 'figure' property?

Comment: I changed it to the 'figure' but then it gives me this: 

"Duplicate callback outputs
11:25:19
In the callback for output(s):
  graph.figure
Output 0 (graph.figure) is already in use.
Any given output can only have one callback that sets it.
To resolve this situation, try combining these into
one callback function, distinguishing the trigger
by using `dash.callback_context` if necessary."

It definitely doesn't like using 'figure' property twice.. Do you think there might be any other solution worth trying out? :(

Comment: The proposed solution should address this problem. Could you update the question will a complete, runnable example? Otherwise, it is not possible to debug.

Comment: Can I send you the actual code and the files via email or any other means of connecting with you?.. It is too big and the files are hard to represent in a simple way here. Let me know if we can do that, otherwise I will try to edit the initial question. Thanks a lot for your help and patience so far though!

Comment: I have updated it and provided a sample dataframe; Let me know if anything else is needed please!